# Many-tag search trailing behind one-tag search?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search

Today I noticed the questions that appeared in the SQL tag were already one hour old when they popped up on my screen.  I looked into it a bit and it appears that if I searched for one tag, it did show the newest questions:

[image]

While if I searched for many tags, I only got hour-old questions:

[image]

Any idea why this is?  Both searches have the Newest tab selected.  But maybe I'm missing something equally obvious (wouldn't be the first time :))

EDIT: This is the multi-tag link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+sql-server+or+mysql+or+perl+or+regex+or+c

This is the single-tag link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql

EDIT2: Retagged as bug hoping for some info on if this is by design or not.

Comment: Done, off now for today!

Comment: I assume one weird caching issue. Not reproducible for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of IDs that come back from a browse or search of any kind are typically are cached for a few minutes. That might be what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It was up to 30 minutes of "lag", but the issue disappeared about a week after I first saw it.  Case closed :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the opposite result.  Multi tag:

[image]

Single tag:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if single tag searches are cached, and multitag 'or' searches simply combine the caches?  I don't know - this is interesting behavior at any rate.

Comment: This shot looks like what I had expected. Is there something I do not get?